# Error building LLVM on Windows - LNK1104

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, llvm

I'm trying to build LLVM-5.0.1 and have had a few issues.

Here are the steps taken to get where I am.

1. Download the [source](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) and extract to a folder.
2. Open cmd and move to the folder.
3. Run `cmake "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-5.0.1.src" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\Program Files\llvm-5.0.1" -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=True -DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=True`
4. Run `cmake --build .`

During the last command it seems to compile parts successfully but towards the end a lot of errors occur as a file isn't found (`LLVM.lib`). I've checked and the file doesn't exist in the source that I have.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\yaml2obj\yaml2obj.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\yaml2obj\yaml2obj.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\bugpoint-passes\BugpointPasses.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\bugpoint\bugpoint.vcxproj" (default target) (160) ->
(Link target) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\bugpoint\bugpoint.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\lib\Transforms\Hello\LLVMHello.vcxproj" (default target) (165) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\lib\Transforms\Hello\LLVMHello.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\lto\LTO.vcxproj" (default target) (169) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\lto\LTO.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llc\llc.vcxproj" (default target) (175) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llc\llc.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\lli\lli.vcxproj" (default target) (176) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\lli\lli.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-ar\llvm-ar.vcxproj" (default target) (179) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-ar\llvm-ar.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-as\llvm-as.vcxproj" (default target) (180) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-as\llvm-as.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-bcanalyzer\llvm-bcanalyzer.vcxproj" (default target) (181) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-bcanalyzer\llvm-bcanalyzer.vcxpro
j]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-c-test\llvm-c-test.vcxproj" (default target) (182) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-c-test\llvm-c-test.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cat\llvm-cat.vcxproj" (default target) (183) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cat\llvm-cat.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cfi-verify\llvm-cfi-verify.vcxproj" (default target) (184) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cfi-verify\llvm-cfi-verify.vcxpro
j]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-config\llvm-config.vcxproj" (default target) (185) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-config\llvm-config.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cov\llvm-cov.vcxproj" (default target) (186) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cov\llvm-cov.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cvtres\llvm-cvtres.vcxproj" (default target) (187) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cvtres\llvm-cvtres.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cxxdump\llvm-cxxdump.vcxproj" (default target) (189) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cxxdump\llvm-cxxdump.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cxxfilt\llvm-cxxfilt.vcxproj" (default target) (190) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-cxxfilt\llvm-cxxfilt.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-demangle-fuzzer\llvm-demangle-fuzzer.vcxproj" (default target) (191) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-demangle-fuzzer\llvm-demangle-fuz
zer.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-diff\llvm-diff.vcxproj" (default target) (192) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-diff\llvm-diff.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-dis\llvm-dis.vcxproj" (default target) (193) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-dis\llvm-dis.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\dsymutil\llvm-dsymutil.vcxproj" (default target) (195) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\dsymutil\llvm-dsymutil.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-dwarfdump\llvm-dwarfdump.vcxproj" (default target) (196) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-dwarfdump\llvm-dwarfdump.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-dwp\llvm-dwp.vcxproj" (default target) (197) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-dwp\llvm-dwp.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-extract\llvm-extract.vcxproj" (default target) (198) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-extract\llvm-extract.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-isel-fuzzer\llvm-isel-fuzzer.vcxproj" (default target) (199) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-isel-fuzzer\llvm-isel-fuzzer.vcxp
roj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-link\llvm-link.vcxproj" (default target) (201) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-link\llvm-link.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-lto\llvm-lto.vcxproj" (default target) (202) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-lto\llvm-lto.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-lto2\llvm-lto2.vcxproj" (default target) (203) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-lto2\llvm-lto2.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-mc\llvm-mc.vcxproj" (default target) (204) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-mc\llvm-mc.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-mcmarkup\llvm-mcmarkup.vcxproj" (default target) (205) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-mcmarkup\llvm-mcmarkup.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-modextract\llvm-modextract.vcxproj" (default target) (206) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-modextract\llvm-modextract.vcxpro
j]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-mt\llvm-mt.vcxproj" (default target) (207) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-mt\llvm-mt.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-nm\llvm-nm.vcxproj" (default target) (209) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-nm\llvm-nm.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-objcopy\llvm-objcopy.vcxproj" (default target) (210) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-objcopy\llvm-objcopy.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-objdump\llvm-objdump.vcxproj" (default target) (211) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-objdump\llvm-objdump.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-opt-fuzzer\llvm-opt-fuzzer.vcxproj" (default target) (212) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-opt-fuzzer\llvm-opt-fuzzer.vcxpro
j]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-opt-report\llvm-opt-report.vcxproj" (default target) (213) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-opt-report\llvm-opt-report.vcxpro
j]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-pdbutil\llvm-pdbutil.vcxproj" (default target) (214) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-pdbutil\llvm-pdbutil.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-profdata\llvm-profdata.vcxproj" (default target) (215) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-profdata\llvm-profdata.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-rc\llvm-rc.vcxproj" (default target) (217) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-rc\llvm-rc.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-readobj\llvm-readelf.vcxproj" (default target) (219) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-readobj\llvm-readobj.vcxproj" (default target) (220) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-readobj\llvm-readobj.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-rtdyld\llvm-rtdyld.vcxproj" (default target) (221) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-rtdyld\llvm-rtdyld.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-size\llvm-size.vcxproj" (default target) (222) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-size\llvm-size.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-special-case-list-fuzzer\llvm-special-case-list-fuzzer.vcxproj" (default target) (223) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-special-case-list-fuzzer\llvm-spe
cial-case-list-fuzzer.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-split\llvm-split.vcxproj" (default target) (224) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-split\llvm-split.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-stress\llvm-stress.vcxproj" (default target) (225) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-stress\llvm-stress.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-strings\llvm-strings.vcxproj" (default target) (226) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-strings\llvm-strings.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-symbolizer\llvm-symbolizer.vcxproj" (default target) (227) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-symbolizer\llvm-symbolizer.vcxpro
j]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-xray\llvm-xray.vcxproj" (default target) (228) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\llvm-xray\llvm-xray.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\obj2yaml\obj2yaml.vcxproj" (default target) (230) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\obj2yaml\obj2yaml.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\opt\opt.vcxproj" (default target) (231) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\opt\opt.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\sancov\sancov.vcxproj" (default target) (232) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\sancov\sancov.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\sanstats\sanstats.vcxproj" (default target) (233) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\sanstats\sanstats.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\verify-uselistorder\verify-uselistorder.vcxproj" (default target) (234) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\verify-uselistorder\verify-uselistorde
r.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\yaml2obj\yaml2obj.vcxproj" (default target) (236) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\Debug\lib\LLVM.lib' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\llvm-master\tools\yaml2obj\yaml2obj.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    54 Error(s)
```

From what I understand I would need to use the extra arguments in the command to generate shared libs for when I use [llvm-hs](https://github.com/llvm-hs/llvm-hs). I believe that would be needed to then set llvm-config on the class path (although I may be wrong). If I run this without the arguments it builds successfully although it looks as though the files aren't all existent in the specified output directory.

What may be the issue here?

Comment: it's not a soultion, just idea. you could use msys2 with gcc and clang, and build build llvm with one of that toolchains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, it seems that building LLVM for Visual Studio with `-DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=True -DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=True` is not all that well supported.

See the following thread on the LLVM mailing list, from June 9th 2017:
[[llvm-dev] Cannot build Clang/LLVM on Windows with LLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2017-June/113925.html).

TL;DR:

> It's unsupported on MS toolchain. It's too hard to make LLVM headers and
>   libs DLL-ready.

Comment: Okay thought I'd leave it going a bit longer just in case anybody else had managed to find a work around. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Michael sure, thanks for accepting. If I come around a workaround or a fix I'll be sure to post it here.

Comment: Thank you! I think for now I'm going to avoid using it and if I need it desperately I'll have to use a Linux VM and go from there.